# iOS 7 alert view automatic trigger

Tags: ios7, uialertview, gimbal

I am pretty new to iOS programming and still learning a lot. I was hoping to make an alert view pop up automatically on a certain screen. Basically I am using the new qualquamm Gimbal beacons for an app. This code triggers a log when a beacon is first found:

```
// FYXVisitDelegate protocol
- (void)didArrive:(FYXVisit *)visit;
{
    // this will be invoked when an authorized transmitter is sighted for the first time
    NSLog(@"I arrived at a Gimbal Beacon!!! %@", visit.transmitter.name);


}
```

What I would like to do is have this trigger a pop up or alert when first found saying what the log says just for testing. I would like to brand the alert but heard that is not possible in iOS 7 anymore so if there are any suggestions for a pop up as well I would love to hear.

This is what I had with no luck (the log still is trigged though):

```
- (void)didArrive:(FYXVisit *)visit;
{
    // this will be invoked when an authorized transmitter is sighted for the first time
    NSLog(@"I arrived at a Gimbal Beacon!!! %@", visit.transmitter.name);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"%@" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"View", visit.transmitter.name, nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Does NSLog show the message?

Comment: Yep. The message is show in the log. I tried adding [alert release] but get an error

Comment: Scratch that, it was a different log showing not the one in here. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: You can't add [alert release] because ARC does it for you.

Comment: So, that NSLog doesn't show, right?

Comment: Sorry, no it was not showing. Once I got the code in the right place it work. Is there any way to brand an alert box or other option

Comment: No, unfortunately not. You can create your own alert box with desired design and layout.

Comment: Thanks. I will close this question then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably your message string assignment, you're using a format string @"%@" but you're missing the call to stringWithFormat:

Old code: (check out the message parameter)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"%@" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"View", visit.transmitter.name, nil];
```

New code: (notice the [NSString stringWithFormat] call)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  visit.transmitter.name] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"View",  visit.transmitter.name, nil];
```

The old code also assigned an alertView button to be named after the transmitter's name.  I kept this in the new code, but remove the "visit.transmitter.name" from the otherButtonTitles: parameter if you don't want it.

Also, if you're looking for updates while a visit is in progress, use this FYXVisitManager delegate method:

- (void)receivedSighting:(FYXVisit *)visit updateTime:(NSDate *)updateTime RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;